# React - Redux, Why affecting all state array elements after add new items into a state array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux, state

I have a redux state array which included some personal infos. This array filling by new items when i clicked a button. Sample array is below

1 st click

CLICK NO - NAME - AGE

```
  1     - DAVID - 48
  1     - JOSH  - 21
  1     - MARIA - 55
```

an after second click i want to see my array such as

```
  1     - DAVID - 48
  1     - JOSH  - 21
  1     - MARIA - 55
  2     - JOHN - 70
  2     - MICHAEL - 18
  2     - SYLVESTER - 33
```

and third,fourth.... etc. So first colum is button click number.

But problem is that All old datas click number changing with new number such as (after second click)

```
  2     - DAVID - 48
  2     - JOSH  - 21
  2     - MARIA - 55
  2     - JOHN - 70
  2     - MICHAEL - 18
  2     - SYLVESTER - 33
```

I never change old datas into array, i just putting new datas, i can't aunderstand why old CLICIK NUMBERS changing with NEW CLICK NUMBER

My tried Redux codes

```
case "ADDNEWDATA": {
     let arr = [...state.mydata];
     arr = [...arr, action.payload.newdata]
     return Object.assign({}, state, { mydata: arr })

}
```

or

```
 case "ADDNEWDATA": {
     let arr = [...state.mydata];
     action.payload.newdata.map((item) => {
            arr = arr.push(item)
     })
     return Object.assign({}, state, { mydata: arr })

}
```

or

```
 case "ADDNEWDATA": {
     return Object.assign({}, state, { mydata: [...state.mydata, action.payload.newdata] })

}
```

I think that i have no code problem, but array is not seems so :(

Comment: can you show code call action `ADDNEWDATA` and newdata's value?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to help but I cannot understand what you are doing from the above. So you state after the first click is {mydata:[{},{}, {}]} ? And your payload would be a new array of [{}, {}, {}], so if you just return [].concat(state.mydata, payload) ?